# Best method for data retrieval for charting

Tags: sql-server, xml, c#-4.0, charts

I have an application developed in C#/ASP.NET and using SQL Server. I am now in the position where I can start bolting on the charting tools for my application. The application displays charts showing the customers data, which is 1 - 30 minute time series and could be over 12 months, so a lot of data (sometimes). My question is around, what is the most efficient and secure method for retrieving and preparing the data for the chart. That is to say, I want the data ready to go when the customer logs in and I want there to be as little lag as possible when the customer logs in to view their charts. It is a simple chart with time series data, but there can be a lot of it.

I want to make sure the performance is great and if i have several hundred users all getting data on the fly, I am going to get lag on the DB.

I had in mind, either creating an XML file for the chart data using SQL server and dropping that into a customer folder and updating this on regular basis. Then the chart uses the XML file I can bolt that straight into the chart.

The other was direct access to the data using a query or stored procedure.

What would you guys use to solve a similar problem.

Comment: SSRS (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159106.aspx) might help you here. It can pre-generate reports, cache and distribute them in different forms.

Comment: Wow, that's changed a lot since I last used it!

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify which version of SQL Server you're using but `FOR XML` was added in SQL Server 2012. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms178107.aspx

I'm using it to fetch complex structured data in a single round-trip, were fetching the same data using LINQ-to-SQL or EF would involve a lot of round-trips.

It may be difficult or inefficient to select your data directly into the structure required by your charting tools, but you could use XSLT to restructure the data before saving the file to disc.

Comment: `FOR XML` is much older than SQL 2012.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb985944.aspx

Comment: Looks like "path mode", which I normally use, was added in SQL Server 2005 but the docs were all restructured for 2012 :-/

Comment: The active docs only go to 2012 because older versions are no longer supported.